# Estimation of rotational and translational Matrix for camera motion OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision

i am trying to implement an algorithm to estimate motion given two Images.
I have used sift algorithm for feature detection.

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(image_gray,None)
```

I also used the Brut force matcher for matching the features of the Images

```
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
match = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)
bestmatch = []
for m,n in match:
    if m.distance < 0.4*n.distance:
        bestmatch.append([m])
```

[image: matched features]

hence i tried to estimate the camera motion by solving for the rotational matrix and translational vector using findessentialmatrix

```
rmat = np.eye(3)
tvec = np.zeros((3, 1))
image1_points = []
image2_points = []
    
for ma in bestmatch:
    ma=ma[0]
    queryidx = mi.queryIdx
    trainidx = mi.trainIdx
  
    x1, y1 = kp1[queryidx].pt
    image1_points.append([x1, y1])
        
    x2, y2 = kp2[trainidx].pt
    image2_points.append([x2, y2])
```

```
E,mask=cv2.findEssentialMat(np.array(image1_points),np.array(image2_points),dataset_handler.k,method=cv2.RANSAC, prob=0.999, threshold=0.5)

retval,R,t,mask=cv2.recoverPose(E,np.array(image1_points),np.array(image2_points),dataset_handler.k)

romat = R
transvec = t
```

the result was not good. Below is an example of what my result looked like as well as the translational vector and rotational Matrix.

Estimated rotation: was a 3X3 with values not upto 1 including negative values

Estimated translation: 3 x 1 vectors with values not upto one and also a negative value

[image: result after motion estimation]

Comment: I think you might check documentation of essential matrix is.. but I could think it could have like 7 freedom degrees? maybe you should check that the sum of allsquares of elements is near 1